# Search WIthout Field Length Normalization

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I omit the fieldLength Norm at search time? I have some documents I want to search and I want to ignore extraneous strings in my query so that things like "parrot" match to "multiple parrots."

So, how can I ignore the field length norm at search time?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - though I think for efficiency reasons this is normally done at index time.  Instead of using tf-idf I used BM25 (which is supposedly better).  BM25 has a coefficient to the field norm term which can be set to 0 so it doesn't effect the solution...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38362244/3071643